# Liquibase: hide author from ChangeSet logging

Tags: logging, liquibase

Is there a way to hide the author from the logs? I want the logs to include the ChangeSet details but not the author so that we are not leaking developer information in customer environments.

Answer (score 1):

The `author` field is not mandatory, so the easiest thing that comes to mind is just to leave the author property blank, or just put your company name instead.

```
 <changeSet id="foo" author="">
    <comment>changeSet without author</comment>
 </changeSet>
```